# Setting a timeout and limiting memory of a process

Tags: linux, bash, cgroups, timeout

I'm trying to run a large process on my machine with a timeout and maximum memory limit. For handling the memory usage, I created a cgroup and use this shell script to start the process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u
set -m

name="$1" && shift

"$@" &
PID=$!

if [[ -f /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/$name/cgroup.procs ]]; then
    echo "[MEMLIMIT] Adding $PID to $name cgroup..."
    echo "$PID" | tee "/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/$name/cgroup.procs"
else
    echo "[MEMLIMIT] Was not able to set memory-limiting, create cgroup first with crtmemcgrp.sh ..."
fi

# Take job back to focus, can then be killed by Ctrl+C
fg
```

Next, I also want to limit the process to running for at most 10 minutes. Hence, I use the following command line:

```
$ timeout 10m ./memlimit cgroup_name ./long_process [args]
```

My problem is, when the timeout expires, it kills the `memlimit` script, but not the `long_process`. My understanding is that the `timeout` command from coreutils creates its own process group and adds itself to it on startup.

As a result, all subsequent `fork()` calls should also be in the same process group and be killed when timeout kills the group.

What is happening here and how can I fix it?